# Biopython: resseq doesn't match pdb file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a PDB file, and I need to extract its residue sequence numbers (`resseq`s). Based on manual inspection of the first few lines of the PDB file (pasted below), I would think that `resseq`s should be `[22, 23, ...]`. However, Biopython's [`Bio.PDB`](http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ) module suggests otherwise (output attached below as well). I wonder if it's a Biopython bug or if I have problems understanding the PDB format.

```
ATOM      1  N   GLY A  22      78.171  89.858  59.231  1.00 21.24           N  
ATOM      2  CA  GLY A  22      79.174  88.827  58.999  1.00 20.87           C  
ATOM      3  C   GLY A  22      80.438  89.415  58.391  1.00 21.89           C  
ATOM      4  O   GLY A  22      80.362  90.202  57.440  1.00 23.18           O  
ATOM      5  N   LEU A  23      81.588  89.069  58.972  1.00 21.51           N  
ATOM      6  CA  LEU A  23      82.895  89.555  58.527  1.00 20.80           C  
ATOM      7  C   LEU A  23      83.288  89.020  57.162  1.00 22.41           C  
ATOM      8  O   LEU A  23      82.889  87.923  56.788  1.00 22.93           O  
ATOM      9  CB  LEU A  23      83.973  89.232  59.560  1.00 20.97           C  
ATOM     10  CG  LEU A  23      84.225  87.818  60.062  1.00 13.32           C  
ATOM     11  CD1 LEU A  23      85.448  87.888  60.939  1.00 15.24           C  
ATOM     12  CD2 LEU A  23      83.035  87.258  60.829  1.00 12.21           C
```

The code I am using to extract `resseq`:

```
...
for i in chain:
    print i.get_full_id()

OUT:('pdb', 0, 'A', (' ', 2, ' '))
    ('pdb', 0, 'A', (' ', 3, ' '))
...
```

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code you use to reproduce this output? How do you get `chain`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `Bio.PDB.Entity.get_full_id`

```
def get_full_id(self):
    """Return the full id.

    The full id is a tuple containing all id's starting from
    the top object (Structure) down to the current object. A full id for
    a Residue object e.g. is something like:

    ("1abc", 0, "A", (" ", 10, "A"))

    This corresponds to:

    Structure with id "1abc"
    Model with id 0
    Chain with id "A"
    Residue with id (" ", 10, "A")

    The Residue id indicates that the residue is not a hetero-residue
    (or a water) because it has a blank hetero field, that its sequence
    identifier is 10 and its insertion code "A".
    """
    # The function implementation below here ...
```

I assume that you are iterating over the atoms of your chain rather than the residues, which gives you the full `id` of each `Atom` not `Residue`.

If you save example residues in a file called `struct.pdb` and run the code below, you get the correct `id`s.

```
>>> structure = PDBParser().get_structure('test', 'struct.pdb')
>>> for residue in structure.get_residues():
...    print(residue.get_full_id())
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 22, ' '))
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 23, ' '))
>>> resseqs = [residue.id[1] for residue in structure.get_residues()]
>>> print(resseqs)
[22, 23]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm soo sorry, I've found a bug in my code after 2 days of searching, and everything's working now (I forgot that I passed a pre-processed PDB to my program rather than the original one) . Thank you for your time and sorry that it's not a very useful question! Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: @AlexMayorov Leave the question in case others have a similar problem.